# Reverse function is not working as expected

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

I am trying to figure out the program: "Write a function reverse(s) that reverses the characte string s. Use it to write a program that reverses its input a line at a time."

I thought the pseudo code like following should work:

"copy string s to tmp, while increasing iterator.
copy string tmp to s, while decreasing initial iterator, increasing new"

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse(char []);

int main(){
    char string[50]="HelloWorld";
    printf("Consider Given string: %s\n",string);
    reverse(string);
    printf("The same string, reversed: %s\n",string);
}

void reverse(char s[]){
    char tmp[50];
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;(tmp[i]=s[i])!='\0';++i);
    for (j=0;i>0;i--,j++)
        s[j]=tmp[i];
}
```

As an output, I am getting:

```
pi@readonly:~/new$ a.out
Consider Given string: HelloWorld
The same string, reversed:
```

When, debugging using gdb, noticed the following:

```
Breakpoint 5, reverse (s=0x7efff5a4 "HelloWorld") at 1.c:18
18                              s[j]=tmp[i];
1: j = 0
2: i = 10
3: tmp = "HelloWorld", '\000' <repeats 15 times>, "\360\377v\334\365\377~\340\372\353v\000\000\000\000\224\365\377~,\006\001\000\300\004"
4: s = 0x7efff5a4 "HelloWorld"
(gdb) n
17                      for (j=0;i>0;i--,j++)
1: j = 0
2: i = 10
3: tmp = "HelloWorld", '\000' <repeats 15 times>, "\360\377v\334\365\377~\340\372\353v\000\000\000\000\224\365\377~,\006\001\000\300\004"
4: s = 0x7efff5a4 ""
(gdb) n

Breakpoint 5, reverse (s=0x7efff5a4 "") at 1.c:18
18                              s[j]=tmp[i];
1: j = 1
2: i = 9
3: tmp = "HelloWorld", '\000' <repeats 15 times>, "\360\377v\334\365\377~\340\372\353v\000\000\000\000\224\365\377~,\006\001\000\300\004"
4: s = 0x7efff5a4 ""
```

Questions:

1) Why do string elements listed in the string `tmp` have suddenly disappeared from the string `s`, at the point, when `i=0`, but, was there, before that step? In other words, what's happened to the string s, at the breakpoint 17, `for (j=0;i>0;i--,j++)`?

2) Is it possible to declare and assign different function types within the same `for` loop, using comma? In other words, why do the below construction is giving error, while trying to compile? Is there a way to mix different identifier types within singe loop?

Construction:

```
void reverse(char s[]){
    for (char tmp[50],int i=j=0;(tmp[i]=s[i])!='\0';++i);
    for (j=0;i>0;i--,j++)
        s[j]=tmp[i];
}
```

Error:

```
pi@readonly:~/new$ cc 1.c
1.c: In function ‘reverse’:
1.c:14:21: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘int’
for (char tmp[50],int i=j=0;(tmp[i]=s[i])!='\0';++i);
                 ^~~
1.c:14:36: error: ‘i’ undeclared (first use in this function)
for (char tmp[50],int i=j=0;(tmp[i]=s[i])!='\0';++i);
                                ^
1.c:14:36: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
1.c:15:8: error: ‘j’ undeclared (first use in this function)
for (j=0;i>0;i--,j++)
    ^
1.c:16:9: error: ‘tmp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
s[j]=tmp[i];
```

Comment: Hint: put the line `printf("string[0] = %hhX\n", string[0]);` at the end of your `main` function and see if that helps you identify your error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the start of this loop:

```
for (j=0;i>0;i--,j++)
    s[j]=tmp[i];
```

`tmp[i]` contains the terminating null byte at the end of the string.  So you copy that null byte to the start of `s`, giving you an empty string.

Subtract 1 from the value of `i` when indexing `tmp`.  That way, you start at the last regular character and end at the first one.

```
for (j=0;i>0;i--,j++)
    s[j]=tmp[i-1];
```

Answer (score 1):

A C-string is terminated by a `\0`-character, and your `reverse`-function copies this string termination character from the end of the source string to the begin of the target string. The target string will be "empty" then, as it is terminated right at the beginning.

You'll have to consider two things:

First, start one before the end when accessing `tmp`:

```
for (j=0;i>0;i--,j++)
    s[j]=tmp[i-1];
```

Second, be sure that the target string is terminated. If the target string is the same as the source string, nothing remains to do since a `\0` is already in place.

If you somehow copied to a different target, you'd have to write `s[j]='\0'` after the loop.